# Extract positions from a list (Python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, chemistry

I have an .xyz file of H2S and if I read the file like so:

```
with open('H2S.xyz','r') as stream:
for line in stream:
    print(line)
```

I get this:

```
3

XYZ file of the hydrogen sulphide molecule

S                  0.00000000    0.00000000    0.10224900

H                  0.00000000    0.96805900   -0.81799200

H                  0.00000000   -0.96805900   -0.81799200
```

The first line gives the number of atoms and the last 3 lines the coordinates of those atoms.

I am supposed to write some code to extract the position of each atom in the molecule, in the form of a list where each element is another list with the atom coordinates.

If I do this:

```
with open('H2S.xyz','r') as stream:
new=list(stream)
new
```

I get each line as an element in the list, and if I do this:

```
with open('H2S.xyz','r') as stream:
new_list=[]
for line in stream:
    new_list=new_list+line.split()
new_list
```

I get every single element seperately:

```
['3','XYZ','file','of','the','hydrogen','sulphide','molecule','S',
'0.00000000','0.00000000','0.10224900','H','0.00000000','0.96805900',
'-0.81799200','H','0.00000000','-0.96805900','-0.81799200']
```

Which I don't want. 
The list I want looks like this:

```
[['0.00000000','0.00000000','0.10224900'],
['0.00000000','0.96805900','-0.81799200'],
['0.00000000','-0.96805900','-0.81799200']]
```

But I'm not sure how to code for this.

Comment: Is there always going to be one molecule per file? And if the molecule is made from more than 3 atoms, will the coordinates always start on the 3rd line?

Comment: @eyllanesc, your edit seems to have destroyed OP's first code output.

Comment: `XYZ file of the hydrogen sulphide molecule` is the second line of the file, obviously.

Comment: Does the original txt have blank lines in the middle of the records?

Comment: Is this the actual format (with the specified amount of whitespaces) of the file?

Comment: @roganjosh I guess so, it was specifically for one question/molecule so it should be sufficient if we assume that. I used your solution and edited it slightly since I am not allowed to use certain functions/methods

Comment: @PedroLobito The original does not have any blank lines if that's what you meant, but the space between the S and the first number is like that in the original file too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should give you the correct output.

```
def parse_xyz(file_name):

    output = []
    with open(file_name) as infile:
        data = infile.readlines()
        for row in data[2:]: # Throw away the first few lines
            if row[1:]: # Throw away the first column
                output.append(row[1:].split())
    return output


result = parse_xyz('h2s.xyz')
print(result)
```

Some notes about what it does:

1. Firstly I wrapped the code in a function. This is generally preferred because it means you can repeat the process with different files e.g. `result = parse_xyz('h2o.xyz')`
2. `for row in data[2:]:` is [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) so we don't start capturing any results for the few starting lines.
3. We repeat the slicing notation in the nested `for` loop, which is equivalent to throwing away the first character(s) of the lines you want to record.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
import re
with open("file.txt", "r") as f: 
    print([re.split(r"\s+", x.strip(), 3) for x in f if len(re.split(r"\s+", x, 3)) == 4])

[['S', '0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.10224900'], ['H', '0.00000000', '0.96805900', '-0.81799200'], ['H', '0.00000000', '-0.96805900', '-0.81799200']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Read all lines of the .xyz file, split element and positions and append the positions to a list.

H2S.xyz

```
    3
XYZ file of the hydrogen sulphide molecule
    S       0.00000000      0.00000000      0.10224900
    H       0.00000000      0.96805900     -0.81799200
    H       0.00000000     -0.96805900     -0.81799200
```

The code

```
with open('H2S.xyz') as data:
    lines=data.readlines()                  # read all lines
    new_list = []
    for atom in lines[2:]:                  # start from third line
        position = atom.split()             # get the values
        new_list.append(position[1:])       # append only the the positions

print(new_list)
```

Your list

```
[['0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.10224900'],
['0.00000000', '0.96805900', '-0.81799200'],
['0.00000000', '-0.96805900', '-0.81799200']]
```